# Is the UK not member of Schengen, Customs Union, Economic Area, Free Trade Association among others anymore now after Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

I have picture showing where the UK is now compared to other countries. (Outside of European Free Trade Association, European Economic Area, Schengen Area, European Union, Eurozone, EU Customs Union).

Is this an accurate representation for where the UK is?

I am not interested in countries other than the UK for this one (although, would be good to point them out if any). I am just interested in if the UK is still part of any of the areas.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140904/discussion-on-question-by-mocas-is-the-uk-not-member-of-schengen-customs-union).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is mostly correct, but arguably incomplete. The UK as a whole is not a member of the EEA, EFTA or the customs union (although Northern Ireland remains in the EU single market due to the Northern Ireland protocol).

The UK is in a Common travel area agreement with Ireland.  It is in the Council of Europe and is a member of the European Court of Human Rights. (And Eurovision ;)). It is a member of Nato. Cyprus, Malta and the UK are also in the Commonwealth.

It also omits several European countries: those in the former Yugoslavia, former Soviet countries, and small nations like Andorra. If these countries are omitted because they are not members of regional economic associations, then the UK should be omitted too!

Comment: For the nitpickers, the UK participates in Eurovision by virtue of its membership in the European Broadcasting Union.

Comment: @phoog Strictly speaking, the European Broadcasting Union is a union of media organizations (i.e., the BBC is the member, not the UK). Moreover, its name is *slightly* misleading anyway, as the EBU has several members in Africa and Asia (not to mention the unusual interest in the ESC they have Down Under)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen fair enough.  The main point is that Eurovision isn't actually the name of an organization but of a network and, by extension, a musical competition.

Comment: Hence my use of the "winking smiley"  This isn't a serious point.

Comment: @phoog : Israel also participates in many European cultural and sports competitions, despite not even being located in Europe.

Answer (score 66):

I saw a similar image a while ago (December 2021) [on Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid02kfre63ivJkStJp1J7x7sTZp8cnt58uVtMSKDCDWtvs4CY3raTb5t7ooKoQDBpWmAl&id=1032532806864578), [originally published by Statista](https://www.statista.com/chart/24212/uk-status-in-european-agreements/) and compiled my own diagram.

My main complaints with that one, which also apply here are:

1. It doesn’t show the before, and the UK was never a member of some of these groups / agreements
2. It misses off some other European (and wider) groups. I wouldn’t expect a diagram to show every agreement in existence (e.g. UN, NATO, UKAUS, Commonwealth, etc), but the CTA feels like a fairly obvious missing one given its European scope and Schengen similarity. The ETFA made it to the list! The various absent Scandinavian treaties are pretty important to those countries.
3. The United Kingdom is 4 countries, with varying relationships to the EU. The United Kingdom is itself a pretty important organisation, and is not just one bloc (in this case).
4. Switzerland, Türkiye, San Marino and Andorra have more nuanced relationships than implied. Plus The Holy See is absent (as is Gibraltar in the OP image)

The original diagram I drew had a number of mistakes, so here is a corrected version:

[image: Diagram of nation state flags grouped by various European Free Trade, Economic and Freedom of Movement treaties, before and after Brexit]

Some countries have a * symbol. This means they have similar or equivalent status to that shown, but through other treaties rather than direct members / signatories.

1. Gibraltar [is not a member of Schengen yet, there’s still negotiations going on](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/dec/31/spain-and-uk-reach-draft-deal-on-post-brexit-status-of-gibraltar).
2. [Switzerland's status is somewhat close to EEA but through bilateral treaties, rather than a direct member](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/factsheets/en/sheet/169/the-european-economic-area-eea-switzerland-and-the-north).
3. Northern Ireland is not a member of the EU Customs Union but, under both the previous ‘[Northern Ireland Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Ireland_Protocol?wprov=sfti1)’ and the current '[Windsor Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windsor_Framework)', it’s partially required to abide by a subset of rules of the EU single market and Customs Union. This was clarified in the linked article, just not in their image.
4. [Turkey is not a member of the EU Customs Union](https://policy.trade.ec.europa.eu/eu-trade-relationships-country-and-region/countries-and-regions/turkiye_en), but there is a bilateral agreement

<sup>Thanks to [Rodrigo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/45021/rodrigo) for these [clarifications](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76892/is-the-uk-not-member-of-schengen-customs-union-economic-area-free-trade-assoc/76896?noredirect=1#comment324399_76896)</sup>

Despite the original diagrams having them, I have excluded Monaco, Andorra, San Marino and The Holy See because their relationships with the EU are complicated, often facilitated by their "host" country. Generally they have freedom of movement and goods, use the Euro and are not members of the EU. Gibraltar remains because it's status was changed by Brexit.

Feel free to share this image with attribution.

Comment: The CTA is a bilateral agreement between the UK and RoI. The UK itself is a unitary state. That is probably why neither featured in Mocas' graphic, of economic blocs made up of many states.

Comment: @CharlieEvans sure, and every diagram has to end somewhere. I just personally felt it should have been included. I don’t see it falling into a different category just because it’s only 2 states. The UK is in many ways a unitary state and in many other ways not.

Comment: @Tim In terms of sovereignty and the ability to make international treaties, it's a unitary state. Northern Ireland, Wales, and Scotland only have the degree of self-rule that the UK parliament has chosen to give them. The UK could choose to define and structure itself as a purely unitary state any time it feels like, and the problems would only be political (not legal). In particular, it was the UK that got to decide whether Northern Ireland would be able to remain in the EU customs union; Northern Ireland could not enter into that treaty on its own intiative.

Comment: Shouldn't Gibraltar also be included in the UK? It would then require the graph to use more complicated shapes than simple rectangles though.

Comment: I think this is the right balance in the context of brexit, mainly because one of the main topic still discussed is the NI Protocol and showing how the UK went from being "all in" to "mostly out, but still with a toe inside" can be helpful in this context. There is also some discussion around the status of Gibraltar but it is not officially part of the UK, it is a British Overseas Territory.

Comment: I am not advocating for this to be updated but I don't see that including Gibraltar really adds anything.  If that is to be there then why not show the French overseas territories (for example).  Splitting the UK up in to four countries reveals that they are all the same in relation to the EU with the exception of NI.  Perhaps "Great Britain" and "Norther Ireland" as two entities would be clearer.  It is useful to highlight that this is the only real integration with the EU that remains insofar as it illuminates the determination from certain quarters to eliminate it.

Comment: @EricNolan sadly, Great Britain is a geographical, not political, entity: it’s the largest island in the archipelago of the British Isles, and so excludes islands in each country (Isle of Wight, Isle of Anglesey, various Scottish islands).

Comment: @vsz Gibraltar has separate status. It’s not part of the United Kingdom, but rather a British overseas territory, along with 13 others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Overseas_Territories. I don’t see much value in adding another 13 flags and a box. It’s also missing the crown dependencies.

Comment: Your attempt to encode the vast number of EU treaties in a single diagram is outstanding. So I’d like to contribute by sharing the following comments: 1. Gibraltar is not a member of Schengen yet, there’s still negotiations going on. 2. Switzerland status is somewhat close to EEA but through bilateral treaties. 3. Northern Ireland is not a member of the EU custom but, under the current ‘Protocol’, it’s partially required to abide by a subset of rules of the EU single market and custom union. 4. Turkey is not a member of the EU customs but both EU and Turkey’s customs have a special union.

Comment: @Tim That is only partly true. Great Britain can, as you say, refer specifically to the island. However, it can also refer to the political entity consisting of England, Scotland and Wales. It's the latter that is used in "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"; if it were the former, the name would have to add all the other islands too :-) [Wikipedia's summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Britain) mentions both definitions.

Comment: @Ben absolutely, but Gibraltar is also restricted in its foreign relations, but I don’t consider it to be part of a unitary state. And the members of the EU are also restricted in making trade agreements, monetary policy, etc, but they’re definitely still separate states. It’s all grey areas. We could even get into the mess of the City of London, crown dependencies, other overseas territories, etc.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff yes, fair point! The other problem would be the absence of a modern flag for GB… and hey, I’m ready for Scottish independence!

Comment: @Rodrigo also Gibraltar actually was in the EU, unlike all other British overseas territories. I’ll have a look for the original file to update…

Comment: @Rodrigo sadly, I don’t have the original SVG to hand. My data hoarding has failed. It looks like the source I was copying from (Statistica) was itself wrong about Gibraltar (https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid02kfre63ivJkStJp1J7x7sTZp8cnt58uVtMSKDCDWtvs4CY3raTb5t7ooKoQDBpWmAl&id=1032532806864578). I’ll edit to add your clarifications.

Comment: @Rodrigo Please look over my edited post and see if there’s any other clarifications worth adding.

Comment: Great diagrams! If you do happen to update them at any point, note that Andorra and San Marino appear to be using the wrong flags.

Comment: @Tim I think there will always be ways on improving the diagram, but it ultimately depends how much detail you want to include. EU treaties are not particularly straightforward, and every member has their own share of 'exceptions' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_territories_of_members_of_the_European_Economic_Area). On the other side, Andorra's flag looks a bit Croatian to me :) and maybe worth adding the Vatican City?

Comment: @Tim Could you explain in which sense Gibraltar is not part of the UK? I would assume all British overseas territories to be part of the UK (in the same way in which, say, all French overseas territories are part of the French Republic, albeit with special rules). It's not like they can run their independent foreign policy!

Comment: @DenisNardin The British Overseas Territories are essentially colonies, albeit largely voluntary ones. There are various differences from French overseas departments, but most notably they are not represented in the House of Commons.

Comment: @DenisNardin the answer is sadly a pretty unsatisfactory one: because the government of the United Kingdom, and so the laws of the United Kingdom, say they are not part of the United Kingdom. We also have Crown Dependencies, with yet another class of relationship and independence, and the City of London. A 1000 year old history plus a colonial past and an anti-colonial present leads to a lot of complexity!

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff, @Rodrigo, @others I've updated the diagrams to fix the identified problems.`

Comment: @CharlieEvans : this has the perk that if there ever comes a desire of independence (it doesn't seem to be the case now, because they are very loyal, for example a 2013 Falkland referendum voted 99.8% in favor of remaining a British overseas territory), then the UK can offer them representation to sway them to remain.

Comment: If one splits up the UK into four "countries" because NI has special relations with the ECU, then one should split Denmark into mainland versus Faroes Islands versus Greenland, as all three of these "countries" have different memberships in the organisations shown.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg this diagram is specifically comparing the UK’s status before and after Brexit. The components of other countries is essentially irrelevant, and falls into the same category as the city states.

Comment: Surely your first complaint about the original Statista diagram should have been that it puts Northern Ireland in two different places at the same time.

Comment: @JdeBP yes: that doesn’t apply to the diagram in the OP. The complaint on this diagram would be not showing NI’s relationship (point 3)

Answer (score 11):

Technically that image is correct, but as a representation of the real situation it is wrong. The UK chose not to join common agreements, but they still have a lot of bilateral agreements that de facto keep the country linked to some of the European associations.

Now there is [The EU-UK Trade and Cooperation Agreement](https://ec.europa.eu/info/strategy/relations-non-eu-countries/relations-united-kingdom/eu-uk-trade-and-cooperation-agreement_en). Plus the [Northern Ireland Protocol](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9333/) which is expiring, but very likely to be renewed.

Apparently the participation to the [EU programmes](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9664/) is still not confirmed, but chances are that it will be.

Comment: The Northen Ireland Protocol is not expiring. The DUP don't like it, and neither do the ERG in the Conservative party, so they keep threatening to withdraw - but absent any specific action to do so, the NIP continues indefinitely.

Comment: I don't want to look it up but I believe that the original plan, still in effect, is for there to be a vote on the NIP after a certain amount of time.  The prediction at the time was that the NIP would be removed at that point (due to the DUP opposition) although that may not be as clear cut any more.  At the time this made it seem odd that there was so much effort to remove a thing by breaking the just made agreement whenever there was a process that could remove it later.  So, if I am right, there is a specific action coming up and depending on which way that goes it will continue or not...